# Creation function that allows to have different count of popups and buttons that can hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create function that allows have a different number of pairs "popup"/"opener-button". Every opener-button should open appropriate popup. But it doesn't work and I can't understand why. Please help me find the source of the problem and advice solutions to have result that I want see.

Problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/f4kc2a84/4/

Script:

```
function InitPopupOpener(options) {
    if (options.opener.length == options.popup.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < options.opener.length; i++) {
            var opener = '.' + options.opener[i];
            var popup = '.' + options.popup[i];
            console.log(opener);
            $(opener).click(function (event) {
                $(popup).toggle();
            });

            $(document).click(function (event) {
                if ($(event.target).closest(popup).length == 0 && $(event.target).attr('class') != opener.substr(1)) {
                    $(popup).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works only for second popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variables `popup` and `opener` will be the same for all the anonymous functions you create; they'll be left as whatever they are at the end of the `for` loop. (This is because of [how Javascript scope works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).)

What you need is to introduce another anonymous function to act as a scope for each invocation of the `for` loop:

```
function InitPopupOpener(options) {
    if (options.opener.length == options.popup.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < options.opener.length; i++) {
            (function(opener, popup) {
                console.log(opener);
                $(opener).click(function (event) {
                    $(popup).toggle();
                });

                $(document).click(function (event) {
                    if ($(event.target).closest(popup).length == 0 && $(event.target).attr('class') != opener.substr(1)) {
                        $(popup).hide();
                    }
                });
            })('.' + options.opener[i], '.' + options.popup[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/f4kc2a84/5/) (jsfiddle), which I believe does what you require.